# Is 'multiple-choice question' a misleading term?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, phrase-usage

In a multiple-choice question there is usually only one correct answer.

In other words, you make a *single* choice from a list of options.

However, 'multiple-choice' suggests that you should be choosing more than one option, so is 'multiple-choice question' a misleading term?

Would it be more appropriate to describe multiple-choice questions as *multiple-option questions*?

Comment: Look up "choice" in a good dictionary.

Comment: See [“Choices” vs. “options”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110445), [Is a “choice” the result of choosing or something to choose from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2711), [When making a decision, how many “choices” are there?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83491)

Comment: Also related: [Do “multiple choice” questions always have only one correct answer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395672)

Comment: So, accepting all definitions of the word means accepting the following sentence as correct: 'You have a choice of four choices on tonight's menu.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Choice* is not just the act of choosing or that which is chosen, it can also be that from which you choose:

> 4 : a number and variety to choose among 
>   - [Merriem-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/choice)
>
> 1.2 A range of possibilities from which one or more may be chosen.
>   - [Oxford living dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/choice)

---

Also, it's not necessary that MCQs have a single correct answer (though that's very common). MCQs with multiple correct answers are not unusual.

Comment: I think it is a confusing term because you could also describe a multiple-choice question as a single-choice question.
Or is that not correct?

Comment: @motrots that depends on the kind of MCQ. As I said, MCQs with multiple correct answers are not unusual. That's why it's standard to have explanatory text (pick the most appropriate option, or pick all correct options, etc.).

Comment: Yes, but I think it is odd that for that specific kind of MCQ that it can simultaneously be described as a multiple-choice question and a single-choice question: both of those descriptions accurately describe it. They seem contradictory. Thank you for your help and patience!

Comment: If you expect English to be logical, you will be disappointed.

Comment: I'm very disappointed.

Comment: Muru, does that mean that if I reach a crossroad in which I can go either left or right, is there one choice or two choices (to my mind it is the former). Is it correct to say either?

Comment: @motrots I would say I have two choices and I have a choice to make.

Comment: A choice of two choices ... that doesn't seem right. Update: though, such a construction is featured here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decide%20between

Comment: For whatever it's worth, being clear in the distinction between a multiple choice question in which one option can be selected and a multiple choice question in which more than one option can be selected is why the latter is colloquially called a "multiple punch question" in data collection and analysis.  Here is an example of it in use. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12725/detect-multi-punch-responses-in-spss-syntax